# iOS : Load image from plist file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I am trying to show various images from a plist file into UIImageView , I wrote my code like this :

```
NSDictionary *picturesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Photos" ofType:@"plist"]];    
    imageArray = [picturesDictionary objectForKey:@"PhotosArray"];
    PhotosInAlbum.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[imageArray objectAtIndex:1]];
```

But actually nothing happens, and my ImageView is empty ! also I have two buttons to forward backward images .

Contents of Plist :
[image]

Comment: can u show the contents of .plist?

Comment: `[PhotosInAlbum release];`.. but where is the `alloc`?

Comment: sorry that was my former code I removed it !

Comment: Btw, you'd better name the instance begin with lowercase, like `photosInAlbum`. That's a good practice. ;)

Comment: PhotosInAlbum is connected through IBOutlet?

Comment: What's the `imageArray` used for? Why you check `pageNumber > [imageArray count]` before `imageArray = [picturesDictionary objectForKey:@"PhotosArray"];`. If your `imageArray` is nil, it'll always return & do nothing. You'd better put more code then..

Comment: I try to show my images via UIPageViewController , this like of code , checks that if pages are less or greater than my images then avoids page turning ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plist is incorrect, it should be

```
Root ---- Dictionary
     PhotosArray ----- Array
         Item 0   ------ String -- Beach.jpg
```

Then add this code to your viewController.. Be sure that the Interface imageView is link to IBOutlet.

```
NSDictionary *picturesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Photos" ofType:@"plist"]];     
NSArray *imageArray = [picturesDictionary objectForKey:@"PhotosArray"]; 
PhotosInAlbum.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
 PhotosInAlbum.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:1]];
```

Your `[imageArray objectAtIndex:1]` will only return image name not its path, so in order to use imageWithContentsOfFile you have to specify the path of your image not only image name.

Answer (score 1):

```
PhotosInAlbum.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[imageArray objectAtIndex:1]];
```

this part should be like this

```
PhotosInAlbum.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:1]];
```

Comment: @Mc.Lover did you alloc PhotosInAlbum ?

Answer (score 0):

`imageWithContentsOfFile:` use a path that is the full or partial path to the file.
You can use `imageNamed:` method instead (which use the name of the file). Just replace

```
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[imageArray objectAtIndex:1]];
```

to

```
[UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:1]];
```

Comment: Check whether you have included those images in your project or not?

Comment: @Mc.Lover are you sure you've add the `PhotosInAlbum` to self.view as a subview? And like what @NuzhatZari said, you'd make sure images are in your project either.

Comment: @Mc.Lover where you are initializing your "PhotosInAlbum" imageView, I could only see that you are adding PhotosInAlbum in view?

Answer (score 0):

initially, `[UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:1]];` would have solved ur problem.
But you are not able to resolve this issue this way which looks like 
the problem seems to be with this line

```
[controller.view addSubview:PhotosInAlbum];
```

it might be the case your controller.**view** is nil at the moment you are trying to add ur imageview.

just make sure it isn't. cos if it is then your PhotosInAlbum is not at all getting added as subview to the `controller.view`.