# how to attach any document in email in iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, email

I am sending email from iphone app it is working fine but i want that with email i should attached a pdf file which is documents folder of the app.for testing first i attached a png from resources folder of app but it does not get attached and not sent in email i am using following code.

```
  - (IBAction)onEmailResult

   {
if ([[MFMailComposeViewController class] canSendMail]) {
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [picker setSubject:@"Pig Game"];


    [picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];

            int a=10;
    int b=100;
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"project existing photo" ofType:@"png"];
    NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    [picker addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"png" fileName:@"icon.png"];

            NSString * emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"My Score %d",a];
    [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
            [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
            [picker release];
           }

else {


    int a=10;
    int b=20;
    NSString *recipients = @"mailto:imran_husain_2000@yahoo.com?&subject=Pig Game";
    NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&body=My Score: %d/%d, My Time: %@", a,b, time];

    NSString *email = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", recipients, body];
    email = [email stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:email]];
      }
     }
```

Comment: why downvote i have written correct code if any thing in is now working in my side so it does not mean to downvote ?

Comment: The MIMIE type doesn't look good.  Try changing it to "image/png" .

Comment: try this two link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486705/storing-image-in-plist

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846620/ios-load-image-from-plist-file

Comment: My guess is that you got a downvote because the question you are asking can easily be answered by running a search.  Of course, he or she should state the reason.

Comment: @TBlue i changed mime type from my side it is working now thansk for you comment

Comment: @TBlue image is attached and when i download that from email it does not open it shows damaged file it shows dimensions 0*0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code snippet.

```
- (NSString *)pathForFile : (NSString *) fileName{
    return [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent: fileName];
}

- (void)sendMailWithAttachedFile:(NSString *) fileName extention:(NSString *) extension{
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    //    NSURL* outputURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:[self pathForResourse:fileName ofType:extension]];
    NSURL* outputURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:[self pathForFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", fileName, extension]]];
    NSData *data=[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:outputURL];
    [picker addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:@"TestOne.pdf"];
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Now Call Send Mail method As:

```
[self sendMailWithAttachedFile:@"TestOne" :@"pdf"];
```

Comment: kFileNameEmailReport what is this and what to give in fileName extension in your code

Comment: i have added the my code in your edit see it does show TestOne.pdf in email but it is not attached in email

Comment: which file i am getting this from documents folder of app and File Name is TestOne how may give that path

Comment: failed to find PDF header: `%PDF' not found.
this gives error

Comment: // Retrieves the document directories from the iOS device
    NSArray* documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);
 NSString* documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* documentDirectoryFilename = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:aFilename];
 
 
 
    // instructs the mutable data object to write its context to a file on disk
    [pdfData writeToFile:documentDirectoryFilename atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"documentDirectoryFileName: %@",documentDirectoryFilename);

Comment: this is where i am saving the pdf file first

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'

Comment: Current update is final hit after it check file writing code.

Comment: i think instead of initWithFile URL we need to get with contentsofFile

Comment: i think i need to post another question with how to attach file from documents directory to email in iphone app

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)displayMailComposerSheet
{
 NSData *soundFile = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:YourDocumentFile];
    [mail addAttachmentData:soundFile mimeType:@".txt" fileName:@"YourDocumentFile.txt"];
}
```

This code implement in displayMailComposerSheet i hope this code is useful for You

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16620891/how-to-attach-any-document-in-email-in-iphone-app this is my question

Answer (score 0):

```
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker1 = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    NSArray *recipentsArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[shopDictValues objectForKey:@"vEmail"], nil];
    picker1.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    picker1.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    [picker1 setSubject:@"Subject"];
    [picker1 setToRecipients:recipentsArray];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSMutableArray *arydefault = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"jacketCount"]];
    for (int i=0;i<arydefault.count;i++)
    {
        NSString *pdfFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@.pdf",[[arydefault objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"productlinename"],[arydefault objectAtIndex:i]]];
        [picker1 addAttachmentData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pdfFilePath] mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Order - %@",[[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%i",[[arr objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"productlinename"],i] componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: [[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""]]];
    }
    NSString *emailBody = @"Email Body goes here.";
    [picker1 setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];
    [self presentModalViewController:picker1 animated:YES];
```

Comment: Here i am attaching number of PDF's. So, I have looped it.

Comment: productlinename this is where may i give my pdf name

Comment: Yes here [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.pdf",yourFileName];