# UIImageView From Plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, plist

I have a table set up that is receiving the data from a plist file, once you tap a tableview cell it takes you to a view controller that shows the content. I would like have an UIImageView at the top of that view controller that gets loaded from the plist.
How would i go about doing that?

Comment: What data is coming from your plist? The name/location of the image file?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846620/ios-load-image-from-plist-file can check here

Comment: @user2843105, this question was asked almost a month ago. Have you had a chance to review any of the provided answers?

Comment: @user2843105, what's the latest on this? Did any of the provided answers help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve plist like this.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Name" ofType:@"plist"]; 
NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

NSArray* allmyKeys = [myDictionary  allValues];
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct method of achieving what you're seeking depends on what information your plist contains. **Assuming** your plist is simply a list of paths to image assets, you can add the following to the `viewDidLoad` function of the view controller in question:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"nameOfPList" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSArray *contentArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

    NSString *pathToFile = [contentArray objectAtIndex:0]; // Assumes plist contains paths to images
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pathToFile];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

    [self.view addSubview:imageView]; // Add the newly instantiated UIImageView to the controller's view
}
```